# how to make letters into words?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a nested list:

```
encode= [['t','h','i','s'],['i','s'],['a','w','s','o','m','e']]
```

and I want to convert the nested list above into a string:

```
"this is awesome"
```

Comment: There even is a [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-list-characters-string/) for this

Comment: No offense intended, but this should be quite easy to find out using google. Did you try?

Comment: I'm sorry, you can't get what you want from your code snippet.

Answer (score 3):

the join in the list comprehension joins the letters into words, then the join outside the list joins the words into a sentence

```
' '.join([''.join(x) for x in encode])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
words = [''.join(word) for word in encode]
sentence = ' '.join(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l =" ".join(["".join(i) for i in encode])
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. This provided answer may be correct, but **it could benefit from an explanation**. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).